# Can we merge similar question on SO

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, clean-up, duplicate-answers

While searching found similar question some of them are marked duplicated but can we merge such type of question which are left unanswered.

**Question:(Unanswered Question)**

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17897746/how-to-integrate-ccavenue-payment-gateway-with-codeigniter)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19419166/how-to-integrate-ccavenue-with-code-igniter)

**Question:(Answered Question)**

- [Answered Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101825/ccavenue-api-integration-with-codeigniter/18119438#18119438)
- [Answered Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858882/cc-avenue-php-integration-not-working/13859212#13859212)

How can we achieve to stop duplication of similar answers and similar question ?

Comment: Just close-vote the duplicate questions, regardless of whether they have answers or not.

Comment: You cannot close a question as a duplicate of a question without answers on main, only on meta. You get the error: "*This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer*" @poke